# How can I estimate a function in a group?

Tags: r, function

I have a data frame with 1530 obs of 6 varaibles. In this dataframe there 51 assets with 30 obs each. I tried to apply de MACD function to obtain two values: macd and signal but show up an error. This is an example:

```
macdusdt <- filtusdt %>% group_by(symbol) %>% do(tail(., n = 30))

macd1m <- macdusdt %>% 
              mutate (signals = MACD(macdusdt$lastPrice, 
             nFast = 12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9, maType = "EMA", percent = T))
```

> Error: Column `signals` must be length 30 (the group size) or one, not 3060

I want to apply de MACD function to every asset in the data frame. The database is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ww8stgsspqi8tef/macdusdt.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Note that you don't need `macdusdt$` within `mutate`.  It would get the full column values instead of the values within the group.  `macdusdt %>% mutate (signals = MACD(lastPrice, nFast = 12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9, maType = "EMA", percent = TRUE))`  Also, as there is no reproducible example, it is not tested

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I changed the code but appears the same error. The database is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ww8stgsspqi8tef/macdusdt.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: You may need to specify the packages used.  From which package, you took `MACD`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie :s, the package is TTR

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data provided, it is giving an error when applied the code

> Error in EMA(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
>     n > number of non-NA values in column(s) 1

To prevent that we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(TTR)
filtusdt %>%
     group_by(symbol) %>%
     slice(tail(row_number(), 30)) %>% 
     mutate(signals = if(n() < sum(is.na(lastPrice))) MACD(lastPrice,  
       nFast = 12, nSlow = 26, nSig = 9, maType = "EMA", percent = TRUE) else NA)
```

It could be an issue because of the subset dataset provided